# Restful Rails Edit vs Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, edit

I was trying to redirect to a different page after editing an entry, I assumed that it was using the update code because you are updating the database.   It took me some time to realise that I was using the wrong action in the controller. Can someone please explain how edit and update work. Why are there two different actions? what are the differences between them?

Comment: I have tasks that can be broken up into two different categories. I have created a controller for each category that links to the same model for tasks.   when i submit the edit form it is redirecting back to the main tasks controllers show action.   It seems to be skipping the com_tasks controller all together (com_tasks = one of the category controllers).   I looked at the html output that is rendered and the form is being submitted to the wrong controller, but I can't see any way to change that.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**edit action** is responsible for rendering the view

**update action** is responsible for interacting with the model (db updates etc)

If you run `rake routes` you will see the difference between the verb and the action. Typically, the create/update actions are used when submitting a form. This differs from the new and edit actions as these are used to render the view (that displays the form to be submitted).

Comment: in what order are they called? what process does it go through?   edit -> update -> edit?        If i put a redirect in edit it won't get to the update?

Comment: Correct. If you want to redirect someone *after* they have updated an entry, you put the redirect in the update action.

Comment: So just 2 events in that chain: edit, which renders the form, then update, when the user submits it. If you redirect_to to go the a different page (default is often the show view in a scaffold), then you'd have a third one.

Comment: thanks for explaining this in a way a beginner can understand!

Answer (score 18):

Another perspective - a bit redundant to highlight similarities and differences:

**New** is the precursor action to render a form, that upon submitting, runs the **Create** action.
(the view is typically redirected back to the index view showing a list of similar items you already **created**)

**Edit** is the precursor action to render a form, that upon submitting, runs the **Update** action.
(the view is typically redirected back to the index view showing a list of similar items you already **created**)