# How to set up Edit for Remote Form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[Webpage View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqsGg.jpg)

So in the image button above, I have a button called "Mark Item as Done". Inside that Item table, I have a date: due_date, string: task_title, text: description, and a boolean: done.

Now I put the `format.js` in the **todoitems_controller.rb** because I figured that would be the best place to put it because I'm calling their edit link

```
    todolist_todoitems GET    /todolists/:todolist_id/todoitems(.:format)          todoitems#index
                       POST   /todolists/:todolist_id/todoitems(.:format)          todoitems#create
 new_todolist_todoitem GET    /todolists/:todolist_id/todoitems/new(.:format)      todoitems#new
edit_todolist_todoitem GET    /todolists/:todolist_id/todoitems/:id/edit(.:format) todoitems#edit
     todolist_todoitem GET    /todolists/:todolist_id/todoitems/:id(.:format)      todoitems#show
                       PATCH  /todolists/:todolist_id/todoitems/:id(.:format)      todoitems#update
                       PUT    /todolists/:todolist_id/todoitems/:id(.:format)      todoitems#update
                       DELETE /todolists/:todolist_id/todoitems/:id(.:format)      todoitems#destroy
             todolists GET    /todolists(.:format)                                 todolists#index
                       POST   /todolists(.:format)                                 todolists#create
          new_todolist GET    /todolists/new(.:format)                             todolists#new
         edit_todolist GET    /todolists/:id/edit(.:format)                        todolists#edit
              todolist GET    /todolists/:id(.:format)                             todolists#show
                       PATCH  /todolists/:id(.:format)                             todolists#update
                       PUT    /todolists/:id(.:format)                             todolists#update
                       DELETE /todolists/:id(.:format)                             todolists#destroy
                  root GET    /                                                    todolists#index
```

Now, should I also be doing something to the `def edit` in the **todoitems_controller.rb** as well or just `def update`? And putting `remote: true` in the `Todolists/_form.html.erb` file, is it the best place to put it there or should I put it in `Todoitems/_form.html.erb` file? And after doing all these, what is the next step?

This is what I've managed to accomplish so far and this is my first time working with remote forms. I'm just struggling to get this started because the lectures are confusing. If there's anything else missing, I'm happy to provide more info about this! Any help would be appreciated!

**todolists/show.html.erb** - Look at `button_to`. That's the part I need help

```
  <p>
    <% @paginate_items.each do |item| %>
    <div class="list">

          <form class="oneLine">
            <a class="notDue">
              <%= item.due_date %>
            </a>
            <a class="linkResults">
              <%= link_to "#{item.task_title}", [@todolist, item], style: "font-weight: bold;" %>
              <%= button_to "Mark Item as Done", remote: true %><br/> <br/>
            </a>
          </form>
        <% end %>
```

**todoitems_controller.rb** - I already put the `render.js` in the update.

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todoitem.update(todoitem_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @todolist, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @todoitem }
        render.js
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @todoitem.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_todoitem
      @todoitem = Todoitem.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_todolist
      @todolist = Todolist.find(params[:todolist_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def todoitem_params
      params.require(:todoitem).permit(:due_date, :task_title, :description, :done, :todolist_id)
    end
```

**todolists/_form.html.erb** - I already put the `remote: true`

```
    <body class="page">
<%= form_for(@todolist, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <% if @todolist.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@todolist.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this todolist from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @todolist.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :list_name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :list_name %>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :list_due_date %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :list_due_date, class: 'dateSelect' %>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<br/>

<% end %>

</body>
```

**todoitems/_form.html.erb**

```
<body class="page">
<%= form_for([@todolist, @todoitem], remote: true) do |f| %>
    <% if @todoitem.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@todoitem.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this todoitem from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @todoitem.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :due_date %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :due_date, class: 'dateSelect' %>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :task_title %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :task_title %>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :description %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :description, size: "40x10" %>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <% if !@todoitem.new_record? %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :done, 'Task Completed' %>
        <%= f.check_box :done %>
      </div>
      <br/>
    <% end %>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
    <br/>
<% end %>
</body>
```

Comment: How could your form be submitted, your forms have no `action-url`. Where is the form data supposed to get submitted?

Comment: Also no `form-elements` like `input`, `checkbox` inside the form

Comment: @illusionist I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: I think your question is quite simple, but you've complicated it by showing way too much code and mixing up forms. Try to reduce your problem and code to achieving one objective. Then add to it. What is todolist.rb, that's not a view. Do we really need to see all that code?

Comment: @margo Sorry, it's a `show.html.erb` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided all the parameters to button_to to make the form work. This helper method generates a form and you need to provide the path for the form to POST to. Have a look at the [docs for the button_to helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) to see what you're missing.

```
<%= button_to "Mark Item as Done", todolist_todoitem_path(@todolist, @todoitem), method: patch, remote_true %>
```

(I'm not sure what your routes are so I made it up.)

When you're updating a resource you need to provide the method (either patch or put is for updating). You might want to read up on routing as well. Initially, they can be a little confusing, but they are at the heart of an interactive rails application so understanding them is key.

Comment: What does the patch method do? And I put the routes list

Comment: Read about routes and CRUD verbs - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions. Sorry to link to docs, but most of the docs will answer your questions. Did you try the above, what happened. Check the network tab in the console to see if your request is being made, or look in the logs to see what is happening. Using the logs and the console is enormously helpful in figuring out where and why things work and dont work.

Comment: Oh I haven't tried it yet. And why would you use todolist_todoitem_path instead of edit_todolist_todoitem_path?

Comment: this should answer that question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910783/restful-rails-edit-vs-update